# pyparsing removing some text and how to capture text with whitespace

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, pyparsing

I am new to using pyparsing (python 2.7) and have a couple of questions about this code:

```
import pyparsing as pp

openBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Literal("{"))
closeBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Literal("}"))
ident = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_" + ".")
otherStuff = pp.Suppress(pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_" + "." + "-" + "+"))
comment = pp.Literal("//") + pp.restOfLine
messageName = ident
messageKw = pp.Suppress("msg")
messageExpr = pp.Forward()
messageExpr << (messageKw + messageName + openBrace +
                pp.Optional(otherStuff) + pp.ZeroOrMore(messageExpr) +
                pp.Optional(otherStuff) + closeBrace).ignore(comment)

print messageExpr.parseString("msg msgName1 { msg msgName2 { some text } }")
```

I don`t really understand why it removes the text "msg" in the inner msgName2. The output is: 
['msgName1', 'Name2']
but I expected:
['msgName1', 'msgName2']

In addition, I was wondering how to capture all other text ("some text") including whitespace between the braces.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. `messageKw` should be defined using the pyparsing Keyword class. Right now you are just matching the literal "msg", so even when that is the leading part of "msgName2", it will match.  Change this to:

   ```
   messageKw = pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword("msg"))
   ```
2. `otherStuff` is a very greedy matcher, and will even match the leading "msg" keyword, which screws up your nested matching. All you need to add is a lookahead in `otherStuff` to make sure that what you are about to match is not the 'msg' keyword:

   ```
   otherStuff = ~messageKw + pp.Suppress(pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_" + "." + "-" + "+"))
   ```

I think with these changes, you should be able to make further progress.

Congratulations, btw, on writing a recursive parser (using the Forward class). This is generally a more advanced parsing topic.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the encouragement. I have another question, but it is different, so I will start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first query:

```
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> 
>>> openBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Literal("{"))
>>> closeBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Literal("}"))
>>> ident = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_" + ".")
>>> otherStuff = pp.Suppress(pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_" + "." + "-" + "+"))
>>> comment = pp.Literal("//") + pp.restOfLine
>>> messageName = ident
>>> messageKw = pp.Suppress("msg")
>>> messageExpr = pp.Forward()
>>> messageExpr << (messageKw + messageName + openBrace +
...                 pp.ZeroOrMore(messageExpr) + pp.ZeroOrMore(otherStuff) +
...             closeBrace).ignore(comment)
Forward: ...
>>> 
>>> print messageExpr.parseString("msg msgName1 { msg msgName2 { some text } }")
['msgName1', 'msgName2']
```

Comment: Doh! That works for this particular case. But what if there can be other text in front of "msg msgName2", like this? print messageExpr.parseString("msg msgName1 { some text msg msgName2 { some text } }")
The following code does not work: [[code]] messageExpr << (messageKw + messageName + openBrace +
                pp.ZeroOrMore(otherStuff) + pp.ZeroOrMore(messageExpr) +
                pp.ZeroOrMore(otherStuff) + closeBrace).ignore(comment)